Hide tooltip of e_mark_line
I have a similar problem as in this post. However somehow all my attempts fail. The goal is that the tooltip works on the bars, but not on the line (e_mark_line()):
library(echarts4r)
tibble::tibble(category = LETTERS[1:4],
       num1 = c(50, 100, 150, 200),
       num2 = c(1,2,3,4)) |> 
  e_charts(category) |>
  e_bar(num1, num2) |>
  e_tooltip(trigger = "item", 
            formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                                        function(params){
                                        return('<strong>' + params.value[0] +
                                        '</strong><br />num1: ' +  params.value[1] +
                                        '<br />num2: ' +  params.name )   }  ")
            ) |>
  e_legend(show = FALSE) |>
  e_mark_line(data = list(yAxis = 100),
              symbol = "none",
              label = list(triggerTooltip = FALSE, silent = TRUE, color = "#000000")) 


The issue is that you have put silent=TRUE in the wrong place, i.e. it is an attribute of e_mark_line not of label, i.e. use e_mark_line(..., silent = TRUE) to silent the tooltip for the mark line:
Note: After a look at the docs label also has no attribute triggerTooltip so I dropped it.
library(echarts4r)
tibble::tibble(
  category = LETTERS[1:4],
  num1 = c(50, 100, 150, 200),
  num2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
) |>
  e_charts(category) |>
  e_bar(
    num1, num2
  ) |>
  e_tooltip(
    trigger = "item",
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(params){
          return('<strong>' + params.value[0] +
            '</strong><br />num1: ' +  params.value[1] +
            '<br />num2: ' +  params.name )
          }
        "
    )
  ) |>
  e_legend(show = FALSE) |>
  e_mark_line(
    data = list(yAxis = 100),
    symbol = "none",
    label = list(color = "#000000"),
    silent = TRUE
  )

